# Observable.fromEvent throwing error in Webstorm

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a directive setup as follows:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Directive({

    selector: '[datepicker]'

})



export class DatepickerDirective implements OnInit{

@Output() changeDate:EventEmitter<any>=  new EventEmitter<any>();
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    const eventStream = Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focusout')
.debounceTime(300);

    eventStream.subscribe(input =>
    {
        //console.log("//////// subscription");
        this.changeDate.emit({targetControl:this.targetControl, targetValue:elementRef.nativeElement.value});

    });
  }
}
```

This works well with VSCode/Chrome. No errors. But does not work in Firefox and Webstorm shows an error saying 'Unresolved function' for the `fromEvent`. Firefox doesn't run the subscribe statement. Any suggestions as to what I might have done wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Webstorm isn't a browser and can't throw an error. There's not enough data to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the poorly worded question.

Changing `focusout` to `blur` fixed it. Webstorm still **shows** an error for `fromEvent` but it now works in all browsers

`Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'blur')`